# Modelling additional fields

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I am trying to pull information about people from ten local data sources for a law enforecement organisation.  I have created a table called Person:

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
 (ID int identity, 
  DateOfBirth datetime, 
  Occupation varchar(100), 
  LastVisit datetime, 
  datecreated datetime, 
  datemodified datetime, 
  primary key (id));
```

Each of the ten databases holds: DateOfBirth, Occupation, LastVisit, datecreated and datemodified so it is simple to create this table.

Some of the databases contain other information.  For example, database 1 contains addresses and database 2 contains vehicles and database 3 contains property and database 4 contains intelligence etc.

I am trying to think of the best way to model these requirements.  I believe there are two options:

1. Create tables for the additional information e.g. Vehicles table, addresses table, property table etc.  There would be a zero to many relationship between Person and each of the additional tables.
2. Use a more dynamic approach i.e. CustomTable1, CustomTable2, CustomTable3 etc.  CustomTable1 would have CustomField1, CustomField2 etc.  This approach would mean introducing a layer of abstraction above the additional tables.  Is there a design pattern for this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Your second point is horrible... if you're going to be creating additional tables (plural) then at least name them properly (so you're back to the first point). If you were to do this all in one table it's known as EAV (Entity Attribute Value).

Answer (score 1):

(whispering) Are you a Java programmer?

If you build a table to store data about vehicles, and you name it "CustomTable17", everybody that writes queries will curse you until your dying day. You will even curse yourself.

Don't do that. In your case, you know every attribute you need to model before you even start. You don't need "more dynamic". You don't need a "layer of abstraction".

Store data about vehicles in a table named "vehicles", unless there's a compelling reason to use a different name. "A more dynamic approach" and "a layer of abstraction" aren't compelling reasons to use a different name.

"This table isn't for just any vehicle. It's only for impounded vehicles." Now *that* would be a compelling reason to use a different name. But we're talking about a name like "impounded_vehicles", not a name like "CustomTable135".

When I've had to consolidate data from multiple sources, I have sometimes found it  useful to store the source of each row. Give that some thought.

Comment: Thanks +1 for: "source id of each row". Is there a pattern name for this?

Comment: *Thanks +1 for: "source id of each row".* You're welcome. That's not what I said, although you can sometimes make a good case for storing the source database and key for each original row. (Some applicatons need that. Some don't.) Professional database developers don't use design patterns in the Gang-of-Four sense. Choosing which attributes to store is usually a part of developing requirements. Choosing how to store them is usually a part of database design and database normalization.